# Magento Store product image another domain?

Tags: image, image-upload

How to store the product images in another domain?
for example, My site is www.mytestsite.com. We need to store the product image in subdomain as "media.mytestsite.com". 
Is it Possible?

We also try to change the media url in backend. But image not uploading. It say as "Unable to create directory 'media.mytestsite.com/media/tmp/catalog/product'. "

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to write your media to another server rather than just serve them from a different domain. This isn't  possible through  configuration in magento. Even if you could you would need the media on the magento server as magento checks on its local filesystem to see if a file exists before serving it to the browser, you would end up with a page of placeholder images.

What you could do to achieve what you are after is use an external disk which is shared via nfs and mounted on both your magento and media servers. That way your media is written locally from magento but available on your second server through the shared drive.

That said, I'm not sure your requirements but a CDN solution may be a better option for you.

Answer (score -1):

Rat, yes, it is possible. Adding your subdomain in `System -> Configuration -> Web -> Unsecure -> Base Media URL` and `System -> Configuration -> Web -> Secure -> Base Media URL` is proper way of doing that.

You also need to subdomain points to `media/` directory.

For second issue, make sure `media/` directory and its subdirectories are writable by web server.

Comment: Hi, I set the Media url. But image not uploaded. And Media folder also set write permission.

Comment: And i have checked for the image and uploaded in media folder in the application server. Where to change the upload folder path?

Comment: So does it uploads properly, but do you want to have it uploaded into different server?

Comment: yes. We need to store the product images in different server.  I have changedthe config media URL as mentioned above, images uploaded in default media directory.

Comment: Magento allows to configure path from which media files are being served but it doesn't let you to configure server/path into which they should be uploaded. You may need to check for some CDN solution eg. OnePica ImageCDN extension to have images synchronized between your media directory and external server.

Comment: This two domain need to be configure on a same sever...

Answer (score -1):

Yes It is possible.

1. Create a Sub-domain named "media.mytestsite.com".
2. Copy the media folder to your sub-domain's root folder.
3. Give the permission 777 to media folder. (Full permission).
4. Go to you magento admin.
5. Go to System -> Configuration -> Web -> Unsecure -> Base Media URL and put "http://media.mytestsite.com/media/".
6. Go to System -> Configuration -> Web -> Secure -> Base Media URL and put "https://media.mytestsite.com/media/".
7. Now save the configuration.
8. Clear/Refresh magento cache.(It is very important)
9. You have done it all... :) Enjoy..

Comment: @ Shoeb Salil : Is it above your steps helps Magento speed?