# Create new VPS save images and file download on magento

Tags: magento2, product-images, cdn

My sites very large size with image and file upload.

So, I would like to setup as CDN from another my server2 VPS from current server1 VPS. That server will be storage images and files upload.

I knew magento can change url storage from baseUrl and baseSecureUrl. However I dont know how to map 2 server and sync that.

Anyone can suggest me step by step create storage like that?

Comment: Is your goal to reduce storage space on your server or to reduce the load on your server from all the image requests and processing?

Comment: @DanRoberts I would like to storage space and image on another server

Comment: Try the Sirv extension. It'll copy your files to another server and delete the Magento generated images fro your server, which you don't need. https://marketplace.magento.com/magictoolbox-sirv.html

Comment: @DanRoberts that extension use amazon S3 and take a lot of cost. Any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

```
          > [ media.vps2.server ] >
user ---->                        -----> [ nfs disk ]
          > [ www.vps1.server   ] >
```

you can use some sort of proxy/cache server config with shared NFS disk.
dynamic will be served from one server, statics will be served from another server,

https://www.google.com/search?q=nginx+proxy+images+to+another+server
https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/

DNS two ip addresses:

1. media.shop.com
2. www.shop.com

media/static base url will be pointed to subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of magento configuration something like this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/68908/70343

To keep media folder in sync something like this

https://serverfault.com/a/665968

Good luck!